# how do i use multiple on taps on the same bottom navbar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

This is my code how do i add multiple on taps so each icon take me to specific
page this is an image

[image]

please help me, I cant figure out how to solve it
i tried inkwell i tried everything it didn't work

the problem is all buttons navigate to the same page if i add navigator there because there is one `ontap`
this is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
import 'package:rive_animation/displaypage.dart';

import '../../../model/menu.dart';
import 'animated_bar.dart';

class BtmNavItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const BtmNavItem(
      {super.key,
      required this.navBar,
      required this.press,
      required this.riveOnInit,
      required this.selectedNav});

  final Menu navBar;
  final VoidCallback press;
  final ValueChanged<Artboard> riveOnInit;
  final Menu selectedNav;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press,

     // },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          AnimatedBar(isActive: selectedNav == navBar),
          SizedBox(
            height: 36,
            width: 36,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: selectedNav == navBar ? 1 : 0.5,
              child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                navBar.rive.src,
                artboard: navBar.rive.artboard,
                onInit: riveOnInit,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where and how do you use this widget. please elaborate more

Comment: well i use this widget to naviage to other taps as shown in image but the proplem is they all navigate to one page because there is one ontap

Comment: you can use `press` callback the place you've used it

Comment: i  dont know how

Answer (score 0):

The `final VoidCallback press;` can be used to change body element.

You can follow this example [I've skipped other property to make it minimal].

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: [
          BtmNavItem(press: () {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = 0;
            });
          }),
          BtmNavItem(press: () {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = 1;
            });
          }),
          BtmNavItem(press: () {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = 2;
            });
          }),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: [Text('1'), Text('2'), Text('3')][currentIndex],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no please show it on the code

Comment: `BtmNavItem` is fine, just check the use case of it. You can focus on `bottomNavigationBar: Row(``how I am setting and  using `currentIndex`.

Comment: can you add it to the code i provided i really dont know how

Comment: sorry that part doesn't included on question, open your display page scaffold and follow this pattern

Comment: yea that cant work because this is not on my main.dart thanks anyway

Comment: you can place the bottomNavBar on main(first) scaffold and use `body` to change for different page.

Comment: how do i  do this